# Given a Java ECPublicKey ECDSA PublicKey, how can I build an SSH2 public key?

Tags: ssh, java, ecc, public-key, ecdsa

I have created a ECDSA key and now need to convert this to SSH2 key.

```
   final KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDSA");
    ECGenParameterSpec params = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp384r1");
    keyGen.initialize(params);
    final KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();

//format publicKey in ssh2
final ECPublicKey ecPublicKey = (ECPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
 
writeJavaECPublicKeyToSSH2(ecPublicKey)  ??
```

How do we implement this?

Comment: you should ask on stack overflow

Comment: Yeah I have asked there as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java